# Not finding a defined block in magento

Tags: magento

I'm following this tutorial http://codemagento.com/2011/03/creating-custom-magento-reports/ creating the simple report module. I have all the code and XML in place but I'm receiving this error

```
2012-05-31T21:48:43+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given, called in /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Super/Awesome/controllers/Adminhtml/Report/ExampleController.php on line 22 and defined  in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 112
```

The structure looks like this

```
Super
  |_ Awesome
      |_Block
      |   |_Adminhtml
      |       |_Report
      |          |_Simple
      |          |   |_Grid.php
      |          |_Simple.php
      |_controllers
      |    |_Adminhtml
      |       |_Report
      |          |_ExampleController.php
      |_etc
      |   |_adminhtml.xml
      |   |_config.xml
      |_Helper
      |   |_Data.php
      |_Model
            |_Mysql4
            |    |_Report
            |    |   |_Simple
            |    |      |_Collection.php
            |    |_Simple.php
            |_Simple.php
```

I assume that it is not finding the block code but why?

Edit

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Super_Awesome>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Super_Awesome>
  </modules>
  <admin>
    <!--
        Here we are telling the Magento router to look for the controllers in the Super_Awesome_controllers_Adminhtml before we look in the
        Mage_Adminhtml module for all urls that begin with /admin/controller_name
     -->
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <awesome before="Mage_Adminhtml">Super_Awesome_Adminhtml</awesome>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <models>
    <awesome>
      <class>Super_Awesome_Model</class>
      <resourceModel>awesome_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </awesome>
    <awesome_mysql4>
      <class>Super_Awesome_Model_Mysql4</class>
      <entities>
        <simple>
          <table>super_awesome_example_simple</table>
        </simple>
      </entities>
    </awesome_mysql4>
  </models>
  <global>
    <resources>
      <awesome_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Super_Awesome</module>
          <class>Super_Awesome_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </awesome_setup>
      <awesome_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </awesome_write>
      <awesome_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </awesome_read>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
      <awesome>
        <class>Super_Awesome_Helper</class>
      </awesome>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

File: app/code/local/Super/Awesome/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Simple.php

```
class Super_Awesome_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Simple extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'awesome';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_report_simple';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('awesome')->__('Simple Report');
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like the error is pretty straightforward. the required argument type is Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, but you are passing it a boolean. it appears to be finding your class ok, but it has this error. you sure the tutorial and your mage version are compatible? post the code arround line 22 in your controller for any further help...

Comment: You are correct in that it is not finding the Block. `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('awesome/adminhtml_report_simple')` is returning `false`. You'll need to post your `config.xml` and `Super_Awesome_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Simple` code, and confirm that the filenames/paths are correct before we can help you.

Comment: Config.xml and Super_Awesome_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Simple class added

Comment: I'm going to check nachito and give a point to Alan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you (or Magento) uses the following code

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('awesome/adminhtml_report_simple')
```

you're saying

> Please create a `adminhtml_report_simple` block from the `awesome` group

Magento needs to know the base name of the class to use for blocks from the awesome group.  If you don't tell Magento what the base name of the class to use for blocks from the awesome group, it can't instantiate a block.  That's why calls to the method are returning `false` instead of returning a block object, and that's why you're getting that exception.

You need to "turn on" blocks for your module by adding a section to your configuration.  Based on your example above, you've already done something similar for helper classes.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <awesome>
                <class>Super_Awesome_Helper</class>
            </awesome>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

That's why your module can use helper classes.  You just need to do the same thing for **block** classes

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <awesome>
                <class>Super_Awesome_Helper</class>
            </awesome>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

That and a cache clear should set you right.  If it doesn't work, trace `createBlock` to determine where it's looking in the configuration for the `blocks/awesome` node.  That's usually enough for me to notice the typo I've been starting at for two hours.

Answer (score 3):

Just got this error but the solution was different.

Everything was declared right, as the index page was being called the same way, using

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('')
```

and I could view it fine.

But the page where I had the error, the block was returning false. As Alan suggested, I went and poked around in `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::createBlock()`. I was looking at the function and did this

```
public function createBlock($type, $name='', array $attributes = array())
{
    echo $name; // ADDED ECHO HERE
    try {
        $block = $this->_getBlockInstance($type, $attributes);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e; // ADDED ECHO HERE
        Mage::logException($e);
        return false;
    }
```

There was an error in the try so it was returning false, hence the error that was displaying, `must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given`. The echo of the actual error showed me that I had errors in my block, calling variables that weren't declared. It was on a new/edit form, so the variables didn't exist if it was a new item. I went through and fixed the errors as they came up until the page loaded without errors.

Hope this helps someone with a similar issue, trying to find a typo in declarations that isn't actually there, I know I was doing that for a bit.

Comment: YEP, it's really helpful to help me to find the real error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `config.xml` is missing some key information, namely a `<blocks>` section to tell Magento where to look for your blocks. I'm not sure why this was hidden way down in the "Complex" section of the tutorial, but oh well. This should do the trick:

```
<config>
  ...
  <global>
    ...
    <blocks>
        <awesome>
            <class>Super_Awesome_Block</class>
        </awesome>
    </blocks>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i post my experience in here to help others.

RYAN's answer is really helpful, and guide me to find my module's bug and fix it.

I got one similar error when custom one grid module:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::
_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given, 
called in /var/www/html/magento2/app/c.....
```

It's system error message, and pretty much looks like mage fails to load and create block!

But actually, error has been caused by using some helper functions in the block. Because this helper has not yet been defined.

So better use following Mage::log is pretty much important and helpful:

```
Mage::log((string) $collection->getSelect(), NULL, 'export-all.log');
Mage::log( var_export($collection->getData(), TRUE), NULL, 'export-coll.log');
```

And when necessary, enable Mage to display error by change index.php as following

```
#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```